# Write a program to read sort and write an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

I have to complete this assignment and I'm struggling with it.

"Write a program, called sort_file, which takes a text file as input and produces an output file which has all the original lines in alphabetical order.

The program should do the following:

Prompt the user for the names of the input and output files. You can prepare an input file with appropriate unsorted data. A simple file with one word per line will suffice.
Declare and define three functions to perform the following tasks:
Read the data from the input file into an array.
Sort the array using the bubble sort algorithm.
Write the sorted data array to the output file."

I have created a .txt file for this program to sort but I'm stuck and just getting more confused the more i look at it. This is what I've gotten done so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZEA 50
#define SIZEB 20

void readFile(char a[]);
void sortFile(char*s[50],int n);
void writeFile();

int main( void ) {
    char name[20];

    printf("PLease enter filename:");
    scanf("%s", &*name);

    readFile(&*name);

    printf("\n");

    sortFile(name);

    printf("\n");

    writeFile();
}

void readFile(char a[]) {
    FILE *cfPtr = NULL;
    char list[SIZEA][SIZEB];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    cfPtr = fopen("unsorted.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(list[i], SIZEA, cfPtr)) {
        list[i][strlen(list[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    j = i;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", list[i]);
    }
}

void sortfile(char*s[50], int n) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int compare;
    char temp[1][10];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            compare = strcmp(s[j], s[j+1]);

            if (compare > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp[0], s[j+1]);
                strcpy(s[j+1], s[j]);
                strcpy(s[j], temp[0]);
            }
        }
}

void writeFile() {    
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen("unsorted.txt", "w");
    fwrite(list, sizeof(char), sizeof(list), cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr);    
}
```

But i'm not sure what to fill for arguments for the functions or hot to get the main body of the program running. I'm a novice and I'm finding this topic hard to understand.

Comment: Always check that `fopen()` worked, even when you open for writing, `if (cfPtr == NULL) disaster();` And be consistent with your styling choices. Your code looks like there were more than 3 programmers writing it.

Comment: Are you sure `temp` is correct? It can be `temp[SIZEB]`, and you don't need to use `temp[0]` instead just `strcpy(temp, s[j + 1]);` note also that `temp` can be very small to hold the strings.

Comment: how do i check that fopen works?

Comment: You didn't read any manual or documentation at all. That's a big mistake. Before using any function [Read the documentation `fopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

Comment: The size parameter for fgets should be SIZEB. In sortfile(), it should be char temp[1][SIZEB]. (You could use char temp[SIZEB], and use strcpy(...temp...)).

Comment: the function: `readfile()` is reading into a local variable,   However, there is no way to pass the contents of that variable: `list[][]` to the `writefile()` function.   Suggest placing `char list[SIZEA][SIZEB];` into the `file global space`.  I.E. before the function: `main()`

Comment: when programming, it is rarely necessary to understand everything when designing the code.  Rather, look at the control flow, then look at the data flow, then look at the details of each small/simple function.   By taking the design in small simple chunks, the designing of the code becomes much simpler.   Even for huge projects, this is still the correct approach although then the concepts of `CSC`s that are brought together to make `CSCI`s  are also involved, (CSC: Computer Software Component) ( CSCI: Computer Software Configuration Item)

Answer (score 1):

regarding this kind of line:

```
scanf("%s", &*name);
```

In C, an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array. (there are a couple of exceptions, but they do not pertain here) so the line should be:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

However, this has a couple of problems.

the format specifier '%s' will allow the user to overrun the input buffer. the %s format specifier needs a max length modifier (and remember that a NUL byte will be automatically appended when using the %s format specifier. Suggest:

```
scanf("%*s", sizeof( name ) -1, name);
```

---

when compiling, (strongly suggest performing compile and link as separate steps) always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic )

---

when prototype'ing a function that has no parameters, do not use:

```
void writeFile();
```

as that is telling the compiler there will be parameters, but they are not being defined yet. Rather use:

```
void writeFile( void );
```

as that tells the compiler there will be no parameters.

Note: the actual function declaration can/should not have the 'void' between the parens

---

when declaring variables and/or parameters use meaningful names. a parameter name like char 'a[]' is (mostly) meaningless. Rather use something like:

```
char * filename
or 
char filename[]
```

---

when #define'ing numeric values, strongly suggest surrounding the numeric value with parens to avoid certain 'text replacement' errors. so this:

```
#define SIZEA 50
```

would be much better written as

```
#define SIZEA (50)
```

---

to check the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful:

```
FILE *fp = NULL: 
...
if( NULL == ( fp = fopen( filename, "r" ) ) 
{ // then error occurred
    perror( "fopen failed" ); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
```

which will write to stderr with the 'fopen failed' text plus the related system error message

---

This line:

```
list[i][strlen(list[i]) - 1] = '\0';
```

will not necessarily eliminate a trailing newline. 
scenario 1: end of file reached and no trailing newline in file. scenario 2: on DOS/Windows a newline is 2 characters, not one.

A correct method (there are several others) would be:

```
char *newline == NULL; 
if( NULL != (newline = strstr( list[i], "\n" ) ) ) 
{ 
    *newline = '\0'; 
}
```

---

regarding this line:

```
while (fgets(list[i], SIZEA, cfPtr))

1. if the input file contains more than SIZEA entries, 
   then the array list[] will be overrun, 
   resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event. 
2. the size of each entry in the array is SIZEB. 
   Therefore suggest using: 

while ( i<SIZEA && fgets(list[i], SIZEB, cfPtr))
```

A more robust method would be: `char **list = NULL;` Then use `realloc()` to update the number of entries in the list and use `readline()` or `getline()` to input/allocate the memory for each entry in the list.

be sure to pass each of the resulting pointers to `free()` to avoid any memory leak,

---

regarding the sortfile() function:

this line has some problems:

```
char temp[1][10]; 

1. an entry can be up to 20 characters line (SIZEB) 
   so 10 is inflexible and too short. 
2. does not need to be a 2D array. Suggest: 

char temp[SIZEB];
...
strcpy(temp, s[j+1]);
strcpy(s[j+1], s[j]);
strcpy(s[j], temp);
```

---

the function: writefile():

fails to implement the problem scenario that the output file name is gotten by prompting the user for the name. rather it is using some hard coded name: `unsorted.txt`. That file name is misleading as the output is sorted, not unsorted.

---

regarding this line in `writefile()`:

```
fwrite(list, sizeof(char), sizeof(list), cfPtr);
```

1. in general, the best practice is the third parameter be 1, to make it easy to perform error checking.
2. the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.
   Suggest swapping the second and third parameters.

However, there are no `<newline>` characters in `list[]` and there is LOTS of uninitialized characters on most rows in the `list[]` array. so the output would be junk. Suggest: output each line separately by :

```
char outBuf[SIZEB+3]; // +3 allows for newline and NUL byte
for( int i = 0; i < SIZEA; i++)
{
    int bytecount = sprintf( outBuf, "%s\n", list[i] );
    fwrite( outBuf, bytecount, 1, cfPtr );
}
```

Note: using `SIZEA` in the `for()` loop assumes that the list[] array use all the entries, I.E. that the input file contains exactly 50 lines.   That may not be true, so the code should keep a count of the number of lines read in the `readfile()` function and use that number in the `sortfile()` and `writefile()` functions.

---

regarding `SIZEA` and `SIZEB`.

those names are rather meaningless.  Suggest:

```
#define MAX_ROWS    (50)
#define MAX_COLUMNS (20)
```

Comment: even with all the `exposed` problems in the answer, I'm not sure I caught everything.